# About priority_queue in c++ using comparator

Tags: c++, std, priority-queue

```
class Node {

public:
    char character;
    int frequency;
    Node *left, *right;

};

class ComparisonClass {

public:
    int operator()(Node *a, Node *b)
    {
        return a->frequency - b->frequency;
    }
};

    priority_queue<Node*, vector<Node*>, ComparisonClass> queue;
```

I want to this:

Example)

Node A : priority 20
Node B : priority 4
Node C : priority 6
Node D : priority 7

after sorting...

Node A(queue's 1st) : priority 20

Node D(queue's 2nd) : priority 7

Node C : priority 6

Node B : priority 4

Such this, I want to arrange priority in descending order.

But error -> Expression: invalid operator<

I can't solve this problem.

How should i fix this code??

this is my overall code

```
class Node {

public:
    char character;
    int frequency;
    Node *left, *right;

};

class ComparisonClass {

public:
    int operator()(Node *a, Node *b)
    {
        return a->frequency - b->frequency;
    }
};


class huffman {

public:
    priority_queue<Node*, vector<Node*>, ComparisonClass> queue;
    hash_map<char, string> *idc = new hash_map<char,string>();

/*  
    Node* huffmanCoding(int n) // incomplete code
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++)
        {
            Node *z = new Node();
            z->right = queue.top();
            queue.pop();
            z->left = queue.top();
            queue.pop();
            z->frequency = z->right->frequency + z->left->frequency;
            queue.push(z);
        }

        return queue.top();
    }
*/          
};



int main()
{
    string str = "AAAAAAABBCCCDEEEEFFFFFFG";

    hash_map<char, int> dictionary;

    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++)
    {
        char temp = str.at(i);

        if (dictionary.find(temp) != dictionary.end())
            dictionary.find(temp)->second++;

        else
            dictionary.insert(hash_map<char,int>::value_type(temp,1));
    }



    huffman *huf = new huffman();
    int number = 0;

    for (hash_map<char, int>::iterator iter = dictionary.begin();
        iter != dictionary.end(); ++iter)
    {
        Node *temp = new Node(); 

        temp->character = iter->first;
        temp->frequency = iter->second;


        huf->queue.push(temp); <- error point
        number++; 
    }

}
```

Comment: Please show the code that has the error.

Comment: i included my overall code and check the error point(huf->queue.push(temp);)

Answer (score 2):

Your comparator is incorrect. It has to return boolean. This should work:

```
class ComparisonClass
{
public:
    bool operator()(Node *a, Node *b)
    {
        return a->frequency < b->frequency;
    }
};
```